# Single Sign On : Get user name pc before authentication on Identity Provider

Tags: spring, security, single-sign-on, kerberos, saml

Well, I am new in security (SSO, SAML, etc).

The scenario We have a Web Application , we want to catch user name (for example windows user) before it has been sent to be authenticated with the Identity Provider (in this case Active Directory) to send this information to another Component which takes this information and send to ActiveDirectory. (This component is like a bridge)

Is this possible? and if the answer is yes. Do you think that we can make an API to integrate to any web application to handle this scenario and get the userName?.

We use Spring, Tomcat. (And we have not decided which tecnology use maybe SAML, Kerberos, etc).

Thanks.

Comment: It should be possible, but I already tried it and gave up on it. It's a pain in the ass and nearly impossible if your server runs on a non windows server. I went with a solution where the user  can use it's windows login at least, but it's non-single-sign-on.

Comment: Using pure SAML this is not possible because Authentication (determination of identity) happens on IdP side, not on SP side (that's the part your app is implementing from SAML point of view).

If you are in pure Windows environment and your clients are all Windows domain clients, then you could use SPNEGO / Kerberos for SSO/Autologin.

Some SP implementations have a hook before sending SAML AuthnRequest to SAML IdP, there you could gather the 'user name'. However what would you do if the IdP later sends a different 'user name' in the assertion? And what about IdP initiated SSO?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @BernhardThalmayr . When you said "SP implementations...." I understand that I can obtain "username" using SPNEGO. So, what happen if I save this userName and dont use SAML but our component (which is going to validate this userName with ActiveDirectory users).

Comment: If you use SPNEGO to obtain the principal from the Kerberos service token in your WebApp, why would you need to validate the principal against AD in the 'bridge component'? I guess I missed something. If a Kerberos service token for your app is sent the user already got a Kerberos ticket granting ticket from AD (acting as KDC). Which means it must exist there and authentication succeeded.